# is there any query to find documents by checking a field of a nested embedded document in mongoDb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Here is my product schema.**

```
const Products: Schema = new Schema({
storeId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'store',
    required: true
},
invoiceId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'invoice'
},
unitPrice: { type: Number },
quantity: { type: Number },

}, { timestamps: true });
```

**Here is my invocie schema**

```
const invoice: Schema = new Schema({
customer: { type: String, default: null },

netTotal: { type: Number },
paid: { type: Number },
type: { type: String },

}, { timestamps: true });
```

**I want to find products where type in invoiceId document is "sale".As invoiceId is a embedded document in product's document containing the invoice details.**

I have tried populate but it doesnt work.

```
Products.find().populate({path : "invoiceId" , match : {type : "sale"} });
```

But it doesnt work and gives all documents just populate the invoiceId of those which are "sale".

Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your `ref: 'invoice'` is correct? Because, usually it is plural like `invoices`.

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: Are you just having trouble with Mongoose or will a mongodb query also be helpful?

Comment: You had better add sample documents and the expected output to the question.

Comment: @AnujPancholi MongoDb query will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I have not used Mongoose yet, but in the comments you said that a mongodb query will also be helpful.

Based on the Mongoose schemas you have described, I mocked 10 documents for products and 3 for invoices using Mockeroo (https://mockaroo.com/). Note that the objectIds are just being taken as integers here but the query should work just as well as long as all ids are objectIds.

**Products**:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "storeId": 1,
  "invoiceId": 3,
  "unitPrice": 127,
  "quantity": 21,
  "timestamp": "1558330027"
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "storeId": 2,
  "invoiceId": 2,
  "unitPrice": 140,
  "quantity": 25,
  "timestamp": "1552293229"
},
{
  "_id": 3,
  "storeId": 1,
  "invoiceId": 2,
  "unitPrice": 192,
  "quantity": 80,
  "timestamp": "1576270154"
}, //and so on...
```

**Invoices**:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "customer": "Y-find",
  "netTotal": 1,
  "paid": true,
  "type": "stale"
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "customer": "Namfix",
  "netTotal": 72,
  "paid": true,
  "type": "sale"
},
{
  "_id": 3,
  "customer": "Opela",
  "netTotal": 67,
  "paid": false,
  "type": "fail"
}
```

As each product is storing one invoiceId, products-invoices is a many-to-one relationship (as many products may have the same invoiceId and therefore belong to the same invoice, however, we are not storing any concrete reference of products in invoices, and each product has only one invoiceId, therfore, one product must belong to only one invoice).

Our goal is to write a query to get all the products where the invoice type is "sale". For this, I have written the following aggregation:

```
db.products.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        "from": "invoices",
        "let": {
            inv_id: "$invoiceId"
        },
        "pipeline": [
        {
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                        "$$inv_id",
                        "$_id"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        ],
        as: "invoice"
    }
  },
  {
      $unwind: {
          path: "$invoice"
      }
  },
  {
      $match: {
        "invoice.type": "sale"
      }
  },
  {
      $unset: "invoice"
  }
])
```

I put in mock data into Mongoplayground and tried it out, here it is:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/K8ciQ-Ei12P

Note that the last $unset stage is only to make sure that all the documents in the result are only the product documents with no details of the invoice (since that is what was required).

Hope it helped. If anyone has any optimizations to point out, or can convert it to Mongoose, feel free.